# Inode vs multi level paging

Tags: virtual-memory, inode

I'm studying for an exam right now and would love an answer to this little confusion I am having.
Inodes have (say) 10 direct, 1 indirect, 1 double indirect, 1 triple indirect pointer.
From those you can access page directories, page tables and finally a physical address so the MMU can map the logical one to the physical one.

Is multi-level paging (say two level address translation) the same thing? Am I missing something here? Is it used for different things?

Comment: Inode and Paging are completely different thing. I wonder what you've learned from your textbook

Answer (score 0):

Inodes and paging are different things.

Inodes are used to track files on disk in most file systems: one file is one inode, directory entries point to an inode, and inodes point to blocks with the contents of the file. Inodes also contain a file’s metadata. (This is a general overview, there are some variations.) How an inode points to blocks varies from one file system to another.

Paging and page tables relate to managing memory. Memory is allocated in pages, and page tables map addresses to physical memory. Page table entries also define access permissions for pages, and can map a page to nothing at all or to swap or another on-disk location for pages which aren’t present in memory. The details of page tables depend on the operating system and the architecture. Ultimately they are used in some form or other to configure the MMU.

See the Wikipedia entries on [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) and [page tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) for more details.